# Make an image responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, coldfusion-9

I am trying to find a way to make my images responsive.

I am using Bootstrap and their is a class name ***"img-responsive"***

However, it is not resizing the images correctly.

The following is what I did to call it and it does not do it correctly:

HTML:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
```

The following is the container which I use from bootstrap.css.

CSS:

```
.container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

UPDATE:

I am using coldfusion and I am trying to use img-responsive. However, it is not working and I am not sure why.

I have used the following css to make the banner images responsive but it does not appear to work

```
/*responsive carousel images*/
figure {
  max-width: 460px;
  max-height: 345px;
}
figure img {
  max-height: 345px;
}
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

and the following coldfusion code:

```
<figure>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="#local.item.getImageURL(argumentCollection=local.imageArgs)#" alt="#HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getTitle())#">
</figure>
```

Comment: When you view your CSS for the images what are you seeing in your DOM tool bar? You can look on the [bootstrap website and see what properties they use to make the images responsive](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images).

Comment: @crazymatt When I see the DOM Tool bar, I see the container being called, which the image is being wrapped in a div, then a row div, and then the image

Comment: But what CSS properties are being applied to your responsive images? i.e. width, height etc

Comment: @crazymatt This is what is being replied based on the bootstrap img-reponsive: 'display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;'

Comment: How is it not working for you? What are you expecting it to do that it is not?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using inline-styles in your `img` tag which affect your `img-responsive` class.

The thing with fixed `width` and `height` is that it makes responsive design difficult.

I recommend that you wrap your `img` in a `figure` and apply a `max-width` and `max-height` instead.

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
figure {
  max-width: 460px;
  max-height: 345px;
}
figure img {
  max-height: 345px;
}
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://fillmurray.com/1000/1000">
</figure>
```

Comment: I have tried your approach and it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Bootstap .img-responsive declare max-width: 100% in .css
But your inline width/height overwrite it

Therefore, you should try not to use inline width="" and height="" in responsive layouts

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will try that.

Comment: Hello, I removed the images width and height and it still didnt work